# [ERROR]: require() of ES Module not supported

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

with sequelize I created a category model, I have always configured the models in the same way but this time when I try to create a record I get an error of importing the nano id library and I have tried adding
"type":module in my package.json but it didn't work.
here is the code of my model and the error

```
// Id Generator
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

// Sequelize and database connection
import sequelize from '@db/db'

// Sequelize Types
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

// Project interface
import { ICategoriesModel } from './types'

// Task log model
import categoriesLogs from '@logs/categories/index'

const db = sequelize()

const CategoriesModel = db.define<ICategoriesModel>(
    'comments',
    {
        cIdAuto: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },

        cId: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
            primaryKey: true
        },

        cDescription: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        },
        cCode: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(255),
            allowNull: false,
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        },
        cState: {
            type: Sequelize.TINYINT,
            allowNull: false,
            onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
        paranoid: true,
        hooks: {
            beforeCreate: (attributes: any, options: any) => {
                const id = !!attributes.cId
                options.rqType = options.updateOnDuplicate
                    ? id
                        ? 'BULKUPDATE'
                        : 'BULKCREATE'
                    : 'CREATE'
                attributes.pId = attributes.cId || nanoid(32)
                return options
            },
            afterUpdate: (attributes: any, options: any) => {
                categoriesLogs
                    .create({
                        ...attributes?.dataValues,
                        aLog: 2,
                        userId: options.context?.uId,
                        createdAt: undefined,
                        updatedAt: undefined,
                        deletedAt: undefined
                    })
                    .catch(() => undefined)

                // Return registered attributes
                return attributes
            },
            afterCreate: (attributes: any, options: any) => {
                categoriesLogs
                    .create({
                        ...attributes?.dataValues,
                        aLog: options.rqType === 'BULKUPDATE' ? 2 : 1,
                        userId: options.context?.uId,
                        createdAt: undefined,
                        updatedAt: undefined,
                        deletedAt: undefined
                    })
                    .catch(() => undefined)

                // Return registered attributes
                return attributes
            }
        }
    }
)

export default CategoriesModel
```

```
[ERROR] 22:15:17 Error: require() of ES Module /home/gadget/Documentos/Code/personal/NodeJs/BlogAPI/node_modules/nanoid/index.js from /home/gadget/Documentos/Code/personal/NodeJs/BlogAPI/src/dataSources/models/categories/index.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/gadget/Documentos/Code/personal/NodeJs/BlogAPI/src/dataSources/models/categories/index.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

```
const query = await categoriesModel.create({
        cId: '1213213',
        cIdAuto: 1,
        cCode: 'test',
        cDescription: '2132132',
        cState: 1
    })
```

tsConfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
        /* Projects */
        // "incremental": true,                              /* Enable incremental compilation */
        // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
        // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                          /* Specify the folder for .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation files. */
        // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects */
        // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
        // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */
        /* Language and Environment */
        "target": "ESNext" /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */,
        // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
        // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
        "experimentalDecorators": true /* Enable experimental support for TC39 stage 2 draft decorators. */,
        // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
        // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h' */
        // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
        // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using `jsx: react-jsx*`.` */
        // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for `createElement`. This only applies when targeting `react` JSX emit. */
        // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
        // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
        /* Modules */
        "module": "commonjs" /* Specify what module code is generated. */,
        "rootDir": "./src" /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */,
        "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */,
        "baseUrl": "./src" /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */,
        "paths": {
            "@rest/*": ["./api/*"],
            "@core/*": ["./core/*"],
            "@dataSources/*": ["./dataSources/*"],
            "@log/*": ["./dataSources/lib/sequelize/log/*"],
            "@lib/*": ["./dataSources/lib/sequelize/*"],
            "@sqlModels/*": ["./dataSources/lib/sequelize/models/*"],
            "@envs/*": ["./env/*"],
            "@errors/*": ["./errors/*"],
            "@utils/*": ["./utils/*"],
            "@validations/*": ["./validations/*"]
        } /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */,
        // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
        // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like `./node_modules/@types`. */
        // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
        // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
        // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files */
        // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow `import`s, `require`s or `<reference>`s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */
        /* JavaScript Support */
        // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the `checkJS` option to get errors from these files. */
        // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
        // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from `node_modules`. Only applicable with `allowJs`. */
        /* Emit */
        // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
        // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
        // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
        // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
        // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If `declaration` is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
        "outDir": "./dist" /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */,
        // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
        // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
        // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
        // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types */
        // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
        // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
        // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
        // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
        // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
        // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
        // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have `@internal` in their JSDoc comments. */
        // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like `__extends` in compiled output. */
        // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
        // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing `const enum` declarations in generated code. */
        // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
        // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */
        /* Interop Constraints */
        // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
        "esModuleInterop": true /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` for type compatibility. */,
        // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */,
        /* Type Checking */
        "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
        // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied `any` type.. */
        // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account `null` and `undefined`. */
        // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
        // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for `bind`, `call`, and `apply` methods match the original function. */
        // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
        // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when `this` is given the type `any`. */
        // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Type catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
        "alwaysStrict": true /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */,
        // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when a local variables aren't read. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read */
        // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
        // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
        // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
        // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type */
        // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
        // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */
        /* Completeness */
        // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": [
```

Comment: [Do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. copy or type the text into the question.](/help/how-to-ask) And with that said: reading the error is important because it tells you _where_ it's going wrong. What is not in the code you're showing in your post.

Comment: Please post the code of *dataSources/models/categories/index.ts* - it seems to use `require()` somewhere?

Comment: the code I put above is what you are asking for and I do not use require() anywhere in my project.

Comment: What settings are you using when compiling your TypeScript?  Have you looked at the generated JS files to see if they are using `require()`?

Comment: I am not compiling it yet I am using ts-node-dev to run the server but I will put the tsconfig.json in the question anyway.

Comment: i solved this downgradind the version of nanoid from 4.0.0 to 3.3.4

Comment: Well, it's getting compiled by ts-node-dev anyway.  TypeScript by itself does not run.  It gets compiled into Javascript and that gets run.

Answer (score 1):

According to there changelog, version 4.0 removed CommonJS support, so you need to use a version lower than 4.0.

Here's an issue that might solve your problem [issue](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/issues/365)
[image]

Comment: Your link points to a 404 page :)

Comment: @djcaesar9114 the issue link has been corrected